# Is it possible to have a code block that isn't highlighted?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting

There are some languages that get highlighted incorrectly. Is it possible to specify a code block that does not have any highlighting when it gets displayed?

Here is an small example of CSS that is getting highlighted as if it was C/C++.

```
#div.a {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.static {
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can display a block without color by using a <pre> block.

```
#div.a {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.static {

}
```

And I think Stack**Overflow** is using [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/), but I haven't figured out how to get it to show CSS yet (though it claims it should, attaching class="prettyprint lang-css" in a pre tag doesn't seem to work.).

**CORRECTION**: Oops, apparently Stack**Overflow** uses [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) not [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) as was previously posted, thx for the [correction](http://beta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19207/is-it-possible-to-have-a-code-block-that-isnt-highlighted#19259) shog9, it's always nice to have the right information.  Despite the correction, the class="prettyprint lang-css" attribute still doesn't seem to work, even with supported languages such as C.

Comment: It will highlight CSS if the lang-css class is present AND lang-css.js is loaded.  Per-language support does not work if the language specific handler is not loaded.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it's [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

As Akdom noted, you can just use a `<pre>` tag and leave out the prettyprint class to get a plain ol' code listing. Alternately, we support [special comment prefixes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to force language-specific highlighting (or turn highlighting off altogether):

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
```

...will properly highlight CSS syntax, while

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

...will turn it off.